# Writing a list to a file in lisp

Tags: io, lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun foo (mylist)
  (with-open-file (str "out.txt"
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :append
                       :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (if mylist
        (progn
          (format str (car mylist))
          (foo (cdr mylist))))))
```

I have two questions. First one is that I can not write an element of a list by this expression `(format str (car mylist))`, Secondly it produces another error as below.

```
             already points to file
             "out.txt", opening the file again for :OUTPUT may produce
             unexpected results
             Open the file anyway
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Error

This error is documented in [the manual](http://clisp.org/impnotes/open.html).
You are calling `foo` recursively and each call opens the file again.
This can have very bad consequences.

## Re-open

You can fix it by moving the recursive call outside of [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm):

```
(defun write-list-to-file-reopen (mylist destination)
  (when mylist
    (with-open-file (str destination
                         :direction :output
                         :if-exists :append
                         :if-does-not-exist :create)
      (prin1 (pop mylist) str)
      (terpri str))
    (write-list-to-file-reopen mylist)))
```

but this is quite inefficient because [`open`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_open.htm) is a relatively expensive operation.

A much better solution would be to iterate

```
(defun write-list-to-file-iterate (mylist destination)
  (with-open-file (str destination
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :append
                       :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (dolist (el mylist)
      (format str "~S~%" el))))
```

or, if you are require to use recursion,

```
(defun write-list-to-file-recursion (mylist destination)
  (with-open-file (str destination
                       :direction :output
                       :if-exists :append
                       :if-does-not-exist :create)
    (labels ((write-list (list)
               (when list
                 (prin1 (pop list) str)
                 (terpri str)
                 (write-list list))))
      (write-list mylist))))
```

## Format

Function [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_format.htm) is relatively
heavy weight and intended for interactive pretty printing, you might
prefer to use simpler functions like [`write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm).

Your problem is because your `(format str x)` should be `(format str "~S~%" x)`:
you forgot the [format string](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm).